# Uneven line spacing across elements of the same page (multicol)

Tags: spacing, multicol, layout

This code

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\setlength\baselineskip{4ex plus 2ex minus 2ex} % Exagerated on purpose

\section{Title}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \lipsum[2]
    \end{multicols}
\section{Title}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \lipsum[2]
    \end{multicols}
\section{Title}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \lipsum[2]
    \end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

produces this

[image].

Is there a way to have a constant line spacing across elements that are in the same page (while still having the stretchable component of baselineskip)?

Goal:

[image]

Comment: It's all open source so there is always a way in theory but "no" is basically the answer here.

Comment: apart from it not being implemented it's hard to see how this could work,multicol needs to know how much vertical space it has to break the text in to columns, you can't easily adjust the stretch after that as it may change how much text fits on a page